# Migrar wordpress de remoto a localhost

Tags: wordpress

Estoy intentando migrar una web en WordPress de un servidor remoto a localhost con xampp.

1. La base de datos se ha importado mediante SQL a mi entorno correctamente

La carpeta con los documentos del wordpress del servidor remoto la he copiado en la carpeta htdocs de Xampp.

[image: htdocs]

He modificado las url en la tabla options de la base de datos

[image: tabla options]

He modificado el archivo wp-config.php para la conexión a la base de datos.

[image: wpconfig]

No obstante, cuando accedo a localhost, lo que se muestra es la pagina 404 y mensaje del navegador de url no segura. Los enlaces no funcionan, el logo tampoco. No se en que punto las rutas están mal o donde modificarlas. He visto varios tutoriales que hacen lo mismo que hago yo pero la pagina se ve correctamente.

[image: url navegador]

[image: no encontrada]

En el .htacces tengo lo siguiente

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php Default.htm index.html home.html welcome.html 
default.html index.htm home.htm welcome.htm default.htm index.php3 
index.shtml home.shtml index.cgi home.cgi home.wml index.wml index.php4 
home.php4 index.php5 index.php6 baustelle.html Index.html Index.htm
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/cache-manifest
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vcard
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vtt
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-component
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-cross-domain-policy
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/ld+json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/manifest+json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/schema+json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.geo+json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-web-app-manifest+json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/eot
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/bmp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/vnd.microsoft.icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css A2419200
ExpiresByType text/x-component A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2419200
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2419200
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2419200
ExpiresByType text/x-js A2419200
ExpiresByType text/html A3600
ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
ExpiresByType video/asf A2419200
ExpiresByType video/avi A2419200
ExpiresByType image/bmp A2419200
ExpiresByType application/java A2419200
ExpiresByType video/divx A2419200
ExpiresByType application/msword A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A2419200
ExpiresByType image/gif A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A2419200
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2419200
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2419200
ExpiresByType application/json A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/midi A2419200
ExpiresByType video/quicktime A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A2419200
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2419200
ExpiresByType video/mpeg A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A2419200
ExpiresByType application/pdf A2419200
ExpiresByType image/png A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A2419200
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-tar A2419200
ExpiresByType image/tiff A2419200
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/wav A2419200
ExpiresByType audio/wma A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A2419200
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2419200
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A2419200
ExpiresByType application/zip A2419200
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
# Las directivas (líneas) entre «BEGIN WordPress» y «END WordPress» son
# generadas dinámicamente y solo deberían ser modificadas mediante 
filtros de WordPress.
# Cualquier cambio en las directivas que hay entre esos marcadores serán 
sobrescritas.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hola José! Subiste la bd a phpmyadmin, verdad?

Comment: Conviene que indiques en la pregunta todos los pasos que has dado, algo como: 1. *He migrado la base de datos, que se llama tal, a local y he probado que funciona*; 2. *En mi entorno local, el Wordpress está instalado en tal carpeta (muestra un esquema de tu rutas y carpetas)*; 3. *En el `wp-config.php` tengo esto (mostrando a qué base de datos estás conectando, asegurando que usuario y contraseña son válidos para el entorno local)*; 4. *En la tabla, he indicado que la URL del sitio sea tal* ... etc.  Así podremos ver en qué has errado. Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: @Inkinvissible si, correcto.

Comment: @A. Cedano la he intentado mejorar, a ver si se entiende mejor

Comment: No es mas facil usar un plugin como All in one migration, creas el backup con ese plugin, te creas en local un wordpress vacio, le intalas a ese wordpress el plugin All in one migration y le subes el backup que habias creado

Comment: Vayamos al punto 1 por ahora: la carpeta con todos los archivos de WP la copiaste directamente en `htdocs` o en una carpeta llamada `circulogastronomico`, o sea en `htdocs/circulogastronomico`?

Comment: Para usar https deberias tener un certificado, que seguro no tenes.. probaste entrar a http????

Comment: @A. Cedano la segunda, dentro de htdocs en una carpeta que se llama circulogastronomico

Comment: @A. Cedano C:\xampp\htdocs\circulogastronomico

Comment: ¿Tienes un archivo **`.htaccess`** OJO, **con dos `s` al final**? Si lo tienes, ¿qué hay escrito en él? Ten en cuenta que para usar WP hay que hacer algunas redirecciones. Haz caso también a lo que te dice @gbianchi, al parecer no tienes un certificado SSL instalado en tu entorno y sin eso no podrás navegar con el protocolo `https`

Comment: [Debes tener al menos esto](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/#basic-wp) en el archivo `.htaccess` de la carpeta donde tienes tu WP instalado.

Comment: @A. Cedano he reeditado la pregunta y he añadido lo que pone en el .htacces. Lo de SSL nunca me lo ha pedido con otros ejercicios en localhost. Lo que me sorprende es que si que muestra la pagina 404 del wordpress con el tema elegido, el menu, footer etc. Pero las URL de cada pagina o cada parte en particular es lo que no debe encontrar. Me sorprende porque he visto varios videos, lo he repetido varias veces y no da este error. Con migrar base de datos, cambiar la url en la tabla options, y reeditar wp-config.php para conectar en localhost con root les va perfectamente.

Comment: El archivo debe llamarse `.htaccess`, con dos `s` al final.

Comment: Primero elimina el htaccess, luego cambia la url por una url completa, incluyendo http://, luego ve a plugins y cambia la carpeta plugins a plugin-old e intenta de nuevo, una vez logres ingresar activa todos los plugins otra vez y actualiza los enlaces permanentes, lo del ssl seguramente es por algun plugin que fuerza el ssl o bien por el htaccess, por eso es mejor desactivar los plugins temporalmente y borrar el htaccess.

Comment: @Jefferzon Bol Funcionó !! Mil gracias a todos. Usar un plugin hubiese sido lo más fácil supongo, pero creo que si me dedico de manera profesional en algún momento,  debo saber manejar todo el sistema de archivos y este tipo de problemas.

Comment: Es facil una migracion de weodpress y hay distintas maneras si o si debes de comprimir el site en .zip
luego exporta el sql luego desde xamp descomprime el site ahi, te metes en php my admin y ahi creas una base de datos e importas el sql borra el htacces y cambia la configuracion del WP_CONFIG.PHP para conectar la base de datos y luego desde la base de datos te metes en la tabla wp_option y modificas url y listo

Comment: Coloca como respuesta lo que funcionó @JoseL., y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero elimina el htaccess, luego cambia la url por una url completa, incluyendo http://, luego ve a plugins y cambia la carpeta plugins a plugin-old e intenta de nuevo, una vez logres ingresar activa todos los plugins otra vez y actualiza los enlaces permanentes, lo del ssl seguramente es por algun plugin que fuerza el ssl o bien por el htaccess, por eso es mejor desactivar los plugins temporalmente y borrar el htaccess. –
Jefferzon Bol